# Manipulating giant MySQL dump files

Tags: mysql, linux, backup, restore

What's the easiest way to get the data for a single table, delete a single table or break up the whole dump file into files each containing individual tables? I usually end up doing a lot of vi regex munging, but I bet there are easier ways to do these things with awk/perl, etc. The first page of Google results brings back a bunch of non-working perl scripts.

Answer (score 12):

When I need to pull a single table from an sql dump, I use a combination of grep, head and tail.

Eg:

```
grep -n "CREATE TABLE" dump.sql
```

This then gives you the line numbers for each one, so if your table is on line 200 and the one after is on line 269, I do:

```
head -n 268 dump.sql > tophalf.sql
tail -n 69 tophalf.sql > yourtable.sql
```

I would imagine you could extend upon those principles to knock up a script that would split the whole thing down into one file per table.

Anyone want a go doing it here?

Another bit that might help start a bash loop going:

```
grep -n "CREATE TABLE " dump.sql  | tr ':`(' '  ' | awk '{print $1, $4}'
```

That gives you a nice list of line numbers and table names like:

```
200 FooTable
269 BarTable
```

Comment: The output of head can be simply piped to tail - this is not a bad idea

Comment: Pretty interesting solution but maatkit can do the same and even more :D

Answer (score 9):

Save yourself a lot of hassle and use `mysqldump -T` if you can.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab):

> --tab=path, -T path
>
> Produce tab-separated data files. For each dumped table, mysqldump
>   creates a tbl_name.sql file that contains the CREATE TABLE statement
>   that creates the table, and a tbl_name.txt file that contains its
>   data. The option value is the directory in which to write the files.
>
> By default, the .txt data files are formatted using tab characters
>   between column values and a newline at the end of each line. The
>   format can be specified explicitly using the --fields-xxx and
>   --lines-terminated-by options.
>
> Note
>  This option should be used only when mysqldump is run on the
>   same machine as the mysqld server. You must have the FILE privilege,
>   and the server must have permission to write files in the directory
>   that you specify.

Answer (score 4):

[This shell script](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script/) will grab the tables you want and pass them to `splitted.sql`.

It’s capable of understanding regular expressions as I’ve added a `sed -r` option.

Also MyDumpSplitter can split the dump into individual table dumps.

Answer (score 2):

[Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/) seems quite appropriate for this with [mk-parallel-dump](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-dump.html) and [mk-parallel-restore](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-restore.html).

Comment: Those tools have both been deprecated and are not considered suitable for use in backups.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late on that one, but if it can help anyone, I had to split a huge SQL dump file in order to import the data to another Mysql server.
what I ended up doing was splitting the dump file using the system command.

**split -l 1000 import.sql splited_file**

The above will split the sql file every 1000 lines.

Hope this helps someone